# Working with Host file in Windows XP?

Tags: web-hosting

I just want to setup a local server on my pc. I have WAMP installed.
Now, for test, I wrote 
    www.google.com www.google.temp
in **hosts** file, in location **C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc**.
But, when I am loading www.google.temp, it's not loading anything.
Actually, I want to make my folder C:/wamp/www/test to load like, www.test.loc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to set up the hosts file like this: (Note: wildcards are not supported)

```
#the hash marks make the system ignore the text here, you can make comments
127.0.0.1 www.google.com
127.0.0.1 google.com
```

You will not be able to visit google.com anymore, so I recommend something like this:

```
#dev server
127.0.0.1 mohan.com #this does not have to exist in real life
127.0.0.1 www.mohan.com

#another host
127.0.0.1 test.loc
127.0.0.1 www.test.loc
```

These are only accessible from your local system. To be public, you have to purchase the domain name.

I'm not quite sure what you did here: `"I wrote www.google.com www.google.temp in hosts file"` but you MUST specify an IP address on the left, and a host name on the right. Windows Hosts File **does not** understand canonical names, being on the left `www.google.com` and on the right `www.google.temp`

EDIT:

Add this to a .htaccess for those redirects.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*).test.loc
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://test.loc/%1 [L]
RewriteBase /
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I want to internally use **localhost/test/*** when i enter urls **www.test.loc/***. Can it be done using something like **127.0.0.1/test/** If it can't be done from hosts file, then what else method will be better for doing this on my local pc.

Comment: See my edited post above, it doesn't align correctly here.

Comment: Thanks again ionFish. Doing all this takes me to the **localhost**, and not to the **localhost/test** folder

Comment: Well, what that was supposed to do is map anything.domain.com to domain.com/anything (requiring you to have a folder there). I am not sure what to tell you now. That's what we use for one of our sites.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking in the wrong place. I'd recommend reading up on some stuff:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webserver

Once all the concepts are clear in your mind you should find it simple to do what you want. The key points are.

- Your local webserver almost certainly listening on `http://127.0.0.1:80/`
- You do not need a DNS / host entry to make use of it.
- The part of the URL after the IP address `http://127.0.0.1:80/eg-this-part` can be configured via your webserver software.